# terraform optional dynamic block based on elements in for_each map

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I want to create a elb loadbalancer where want to create optional "access_logs" block as shown below.

```
dynamic "access_logs" {
        for_each = "${var.settings}"
        content {
            bucket = access_logs.value[alb_bucket_name]
            bucket_prefix = access_logs.value[alb_bucket_prefix]
            interval = access_logs..value[alb_bucket_interval]
        }
  }
```

if i declare empty settings map then it should not create "access_logs" object, if i provide values in settings, then it should create the "access_logs" object in elb resource.

please help on this scenario?

Comment: The code in your question will already accomplish what you are asking.

Comment: thank you for your comment, i worked on this and is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Below is working script for access_logs optional block

```sh
## optional block

dynamic "access_logs" {
    for_each = "${var.access_logs}"
    content {
        bucket = "${access_logs.value.lb_bucket_name}"
        bucket_prefix = "${access_logs.value.lb_bucket_prefix}"
        interval = "${access_logs.value.lb_bucket_interval}"
    }
  }
```

below is the variables file

```
## vars.tf
variable "access_logs" {
    type = list(object({
        lb_bucket_name = string
        lb_bucket_prefix = string
        lb_bucket_interval = string
    }))
    default = []
}
```